# jQuery is not working over the colobox

Tags: jquery

I am trying to run click event over the colorbox but jquery is seems not working over the colorbox popup?

```
$(document).on('click', "#click", function () {
  alert("working");
});
```

Comment: Show the html code its important before you posting

Comment: `$( "#myId" ).click(function() { alert( "working" ); });` or if you've provided a class for your element: `$( ".myClass" ).click(function() { alert( "working" ); });`

Comment: I have a button over the popup of colorbox which has id "click" but nothing is happening,alert is working on the page but over the popup it  is not working...

Comment: @urbz per the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/click/) `This method is a shortcut for .on( "click", handler )`. Although miniscule, using your advice would produce additional overhead. Johny is properly using the `.on()` handler as it allows for delegated events and is overall recommended for better performance when used properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.

```
$("#click").on("click", function(){
  alert("Clicked");
});
```